# Calculate a triple integral where the integrand contains cubic terms

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Calculate
$$I = \iiint\limits_Q(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
where $Q: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2ax-2ay-2az + 2a^2 = 0$ is a sphere

If I try using spherical coordinates I don't go anywhere. Any hint about
how to calculate it?

Comment: $Q$ is not centered at origin. Do a change of variable so $Q: X^2+Y^2+Z^2=a^2$.

Comment: Have you tried changing the variables and exploiting the symmetry?

Comment: Are you sure it is triple integral? I think it should be the surface integral or double integral since sphere is a surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to symmetry
$$I = \iiint_Q(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)\,dV
=3 \iiint_Q z^3\,dV$$
Then, recenter the sphere at origin and integrate in spherical coordinates
\begin{align}
I =& \ 3 \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2<a^2} (z+a)^3\,dV
 =\ 3 \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2<a^2} (3az^2 +a^3)\,dV\\
 =& \ 3a \iiint_{r<a} r^2 \ r^2\sin\phi dr d\theta d\phi + 3a^3 \cdot \frac43\pi a^3=\frac{32}5\pi a^6
\end{align}

Comment: Did you use that $\iiint_Q (x^3+y^3+z^3)dV=\iiint_Q x^3 dV+\iiint_Q y^3 dV+\iiint_Q z^3 dV$ and noticed that, exchanging $x$ with $z$ and exchanging $y$ with $z$, the set $Q$ doesn't change, hence the value of the integral is the triple of one of the integrals in the sum? If yes, what kind of symmetry is this?

Comment: @ZaWarudo - not sure there is a specific name, perhaps ‘exchange’ symmetry